# Creating and importing marker symbols (or 'Style References') in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, symbology

I work with ArcMap 10 and many different federal lands all of which can be associated with iconic logos (think National Park Service, National Wildlife Refuge System, etc.).  I'd like to create a 'Style Reference' that has all of the different logos to denote point data.

This will be a working style reference as I encounter new features from time to time.

How can I maintain or edit a style reference?

I'm assuming the preferred format would be .emf (vector) to maintain transparency, but I'm not at all familiar with the style format structure or file type.

[image: National Park Service]                    [image: National Wildlife Refuge System]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Style Manager** dialog box lets you organize styles and their contents (symbols and map elements).

Use the **Marker Symbols** to store your custom logos etc.

You can save the style out to a file (.style) and import it to other installs of ArcGIS

[image]

If have a licence above Basic (Arcview)
ArcGIS for Desktop Standard (ArcEditor) and ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced (ArcInfo)

There is also **Cartographic Representations** that can override Marker Symbols 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000004m000000

Comment: Do marker symbols in the style manager support transparency through .emf?

Comment: with .emf file - yes.